# Webcam picture keeps freezing

Tags: video, webcam

I have a Logitech QuickCam Communicate STX webcan that was plug and play when I bought it a few years back. I have used it a few times on Skype when it seemed okay, but have been trying to use it with Google+ Hangouts. There I found that it would be okay at first, but then the picture would freeze. Sound through the built-in microphone is fine.

I wondered if it was the Google plug-in, but just doing some experiments with Cheese and that freezes too. I can seem to un-freeze that (for a second or 2) by waving a hand in front of the camera. Could something be shutting down if it doesn't detect enough movement?

I'm running Kubuntu 11.10. Any suggestions on things to look at?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's too localized: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libv4l/+bug/984603

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04, kernel 4.15.0-118-generic and I had similar problems and multiple errors in `dmesg` output: `ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 4 comp_code 13. Looking for event-dma 00000000fff98180 trb-start 00000000fff98150 trb-end 00000000fff98160 seg-start 00000000fff98000 seg-end 00000000fff98ff0`. Problem was solved by googling forums answers related to this error and **using another USB port**. It's a kernel bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1749961

Answer (score 2):

Many applications, like webcams, doesn't seem to work well (or at all) with V4L2. But luckily there is a simple workaround to avoid the problem, through installing and loading some libraries with backward-compatibility with V4L, so that Flash sees again your Webcam, as it used to do until Ubuntu Hardy.

> sudo apt-get install ld.so.preload-manager

after that execute:

> sudo ld.so.preload-manager /usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so

Then, you have to switch the video mode to V4L from the multimedia systems selector, through executing the following in a terminal:

> gstreamer-properties

Go to the Video tab, and change the default value to V4L.

Comment: ld.so.preload-manager doesn't seem to be available as a package on 11.10.

I see your answer came from UBuntu wiki. Maybe that needs updating https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam/Troubleshooting#Fixing_Webcam_issues_while_using_Flash_since_Intrepid

Comment: thanks for finding the source... I had cut-n-pasted that to a set of notes I have for my kids computers and did not have the source. They are on 11.04 so it looks like I too will be looking for a new set of instructions.